# Can i get suricata to listen to localhost

Tags: intrusion-detection, suricata, libnids

I'm trying to get suricata to listen to the localhost interface, but it says that there is 
 ERRCODE: SC_ERR_SYSCALL(50) failure to get feature via ioctl for 'lo'

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first time setting up Suricata?
How exactly are you calling Suricata?

`sudo /usr/bin/suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i eth0`

Why do you want to listen on the localhost (lo) interface, when you would use eth0?

Perhaps you do not want to set this up to be available on the public interface. Please note you can still run Suricata on eth0 and do whatever testing you may have in mind on the local host (This is with out further context of your setup here)